# Pycharm 2017.x hanging at opening a project the second time on Mac

Tags: pycharm, macos-sierra

I detected a bug on Pycharm2017 Professional (both in 2017.1 and 2017.1.1), so the first time you open the new version it works fine, but after closing Pycharm (Cmd+Q) **in the second boot of the project after the project selector it hangs completely**. I've tried to download fresh, install fresh, etc. but the only workaround (pretty annoying) I found is to execute always *before* opening the second time this command `rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm2017.1`.

In my office we are several guys using PyCharm and most of them using PyCharm Professional 2017 but it's only happening to me for certain projects I only have, so it seems project related. **Not happening on 2016.3**. Anyone suffering from the same or having lived this and has a better workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a solution from Pycharm developers and bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23980

The problem was with the **basisjs** plugin which I did not even remembered when I installed and why (a pro user of PyCharm for years), **uninstalling it solves the problem**.

As conclusion the plugin ecosystem versioning and testing should be improved y the Intellij guys, I found pretty annoying to have the product totally unusable because of a tiny plugin there when they release a new version I'm paying for (license includes 12-month upgrades).